# Javascript: Jquery Select-Object-by-Attribute-Value doen't work with className

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to remove the class "selected" from the object `<a>`. If I give `<a>` it an ID I can call it by ID and remove its current class by `document.getElementByID("id_of_a").className = "";`

However, in case I don't want to give it an ID, I use Jquery Attribute="value" to select the object and then add .className after it. But className  seems doesn't work. I tried to add the function hide() to test if the jquery code is working. The hide() works but I can't use .className to remove its class.

```
<a class = "selected" href = "project_1" onclick = "changeTab()"> Link </a>

<script>
function changeTab() {
$('a[href="project_1"]').className = "";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how you set the class name when you're using jQuery:

```
$('a[href="project_1"]').attr("class", "");
```

The objects you get back from `$()` are *not* DOM elements — they're jQuery objects, and they have their own behaviors. In general there's a way to do any DOM manipulation supported natively via jQuery APIs, and you can always access the actual DOM element if you need to.

It would be more idiomatic to use the jQuery `.removeClass()` API to clear the "class" attribute:

```
$('a[href="project_1"]').removeClass();
```

Passing nothing to that method will remove all classes.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you very much.